# Enabling the push notification service for an existing application in IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an application in IPhone  in which i am trying to implement push notification.I have already created the appstore and adhoc certificates for this project.Now i was in deep confusion how to enable push notification for the existing certificates.Can any body give me the steps to follow.when i am going trough google i only got a vague idea.can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

use this tutorial. they have great explaination to this

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2

Comment: I have already gone through this. but my question how to enable this for already created certificates?

Comment: goto apple developer> provisioning center> appids> configure(app what on u r wrking) > enable pushnotification

Comment: and run it. all this is one part. and there is a 2nd part

Comment: in 2nd part. you may refer to this link

Comment: You r right but how can i upvote for your answer.becoz Your comments are right??

Comment: sure why not. u can upvot, as well can upvote  my comments too